# Python: how to get this elegantly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and I wrote a function:

```
def f(x, y, z):
    ret = []
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            for k in range(z):
                ret.append((i, j, k))
    return ret


print f(2, 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

But I'm not satisfied with that because I think there must be a shorter implementation.

So could any one give me some hint about that?

Comment: Well, if your code works and you want to improve it, [Code Reviews SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for your question. Check what's on-topic questions here and there for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) because that is essentially what you are after, the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(range(2), range(3), range(4)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

So replacing your existing function you could do

```
def f(x, y, z):
    return list(product(range(x), range(y), range(z)))
```

To remove the number of times you have to type out `range`, you could accept a single list argument then use a generator expression such as

```
def f(l):
    return list(product(*(range(i) for i in l)))
```

So then you could call it as

```
>>> f([2,3,4])
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: wow, I had never thought there is such a cool function in python!

Comment: @CoryKarmer the best answer.. ..Awesome

Comment: I find `print list(product(range(2), range(2), range(2), range(2)))` is correct, but I want to eliminate the repeat `range(2)`, so I come to `print list(product([range(2)] * 4))` which output is wrong. Is there any way to eliminate repeat `range(2)` here?

Comment: itertools is where the cool stuff happens in python :)

Comment: @Sayakiss See my edit, you could modify your function to take a single list argument, will that more flexible for you?

Comment: @Sayakiss `list(product(*map(range, repeat(2, 4))))`

Comment: @CoryKramer Maybe it will be useful in the future. In this case which I'm working with now, `f(x,y,z)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
 >>> [(i, j, k) for i in range(2) for j in range(3) for k in range(4)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

You you can write the function like:

```
def f(x, y, z):
    return [(i, j, k) for i in range(x) for j in range(y) for k in range(z)]
```